# Prepare запрос возвращает не верный результат

Tags: php, sql

Есть простой запрос, который работает, но если ввести ', то он не сработает, чтобы этого не было пытался сделать `prepare` запрос, но он в результате выдаёт 0, хотя это не так и входит в условие. Как это исправить? Я пытался и через `fetchColumn()`, и через `$empty = $query->rowCount() === 0;
var_dump($empty); if ($empty)`, но они оба не сработали

Рабочий запрос(действительно есть такой пользователь и в if не заходит)

```
$checkPoluch = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$namePol'");
      $empty = mysqli_num_rows($checkPoluch);
      if ($empty == 0) {        
        echo "Ошибка!";
        exit("");
      }
```

Через `prepare` (В if заходит, даже если есть такой логин)

```
$checkPoluch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?";
  $query = $db->prepare($checkPoluch);
  $query->bind_param("s", $namePol);
  $query->execute();
  $empty = $query->num_rows;
  if ($empty == 0) {
    echo "Ошибка!";
    exit("");
  }
```

Comment: каждая из используемых функций возвращает некий результат, который обычно false в случае ошибки. Проверьте эти значения, т.к. выглядит вроде все корректно,  если конечно вы уверены, что такой логин в таблице точно присутствует

Comment: @teran, Да я уверен, что логин такой есть. И в первом случае всё нормально, в отличие от второго с `prepare`. Я пытался сделать `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE login = ?`, но тоже не помогло: `$query->num_rows` всё равно выдаёт 0.

Comment: дак вы проверили результаты bind_param/execute ?

Comment: @teran, пока искал как проверить ЧТО забиндилось и как выполнился execute, случайно нашёл ответ на вопрос. Можете показать пример того как проверить результаты bind_param/execute (думаю просто `if(bind_param/execute)` это не то, что вы просили)

Comment: то, только в случае false вывести текст ошибки PDO, функции для этого тоже имеются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, необходимо было получить результат перед подсчётом строк. После редактирования, код сработал и выдал нужный результат:

```
$checkPoluch = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = ?";      
$query = $db->prepare($checkPoluch);
$query->bind_param("s", $namePol);
$query->execute();

$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($check);
$query->fetch();

$empty = $query->num_rows();

if ($empty == 0) {      
  echo "Ошибка!";
  exit("");
}else{
  echo "Сработало!";
  exit("");
}
```